# Python Why must multiprocessing.set_start_method be invoked in the __name__ == '__main__' clause?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

If you want to spawn a process, instead of fork a process, using `multiprocess` module, you can use the following command:

```
multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) states:

> To select a start method you use the set_start_method() in the if `__name__ == '__main__'` clause of the main module

However, I've found that I can call `set_start_method('spawn')` outside of the `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause, and it still spawns instead of forks processes on Unix.

In fact, as long as you invoke `set_start_method('spawn')` prior to the first invocation of `multiprocessing.Process()`, it will behave as expected. If you instead attempt to call `set_start_method('spawn')` after the first `multiprocessing.Process()`, it seems to be ignored and will fork instead of spawn.

Why does the documentation state that `set_start_method` should be invoked inside the `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause?

Answer (score 5):

Sub-processes do not enter the `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause. That way we can guarantee `set_start_method` will be called only once.

It does not need to be specifically at the module level, but it can be in any function that is ran through that clause, and still guarantee only one invocation.

Comment: If I call `set_start_method('spawn', force=True)`, it appears to be fine if it is called twice. Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: Yes, why would you override it twice?